How should warning information be sent to the client from the server in WebSockets?
I have an application that uses websockets to send the client notifications in real time. Before establishing the handshake, on the server side some operations are performed with some query params that arrive from the client's request. Some of these operations may result in "warnings"/, but some of these warnings are acceptable, that is, the frontend should know that something happened but these errors are not a reason not to set the handshake. How should I send that information to the client? In the response headers, or in any message once the websocket has already started?

The latter, I believe.
